# How to Show text on screen in AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I am not a coder but i found AHK to be usefull

currently i have a little script to toggle the widows button on and off (enable and disable) and I just need to add some text to indicate whether it is on or off, my current I found a GUI script that would write "on" but id does nothing else (so the on message just stays on screen forever)

my current script is:

```
PrintScreen::Send #{PrintScreen}
LWin::Return
RWin::Return

#If GetKeyState("CapsLock","T")
LWin::Send #{PrintScreen}
RWin::Send #{PrintScreen}
#If

f12::
Suspend
#SingleInstance, force

Gui, Color, White

Gui, -caption +toolwindow +AlwaysOnTop

Gui, font, s30 bold, Arial

Gui, add, text, vTX cRed TransColor, On

Gui, Show, % "x" A_ScreenWidth-300 " y" A_ScreenHeight-130 ,TRANS-WIN

WinSet, TransColor, White, TRANS-WIN

return



OnOff:  

    GuiControl, % (toggle := F12 ) ? "Hide" : "Show", TX

return

ExitApp



GuiEscape:

   ExitApp

return
return
```

Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Tested to work:

```
PrintScreen::Send #{PrintScreen}
LWin::
RWin::Return

#If GetKeyState("CapsLock","T")
    LWin::
    RWin::Send #{PrintScreen}
#If

F12::
    Suspend
    ShowOnOff()
Return

ShowOnOff() {
    Static TX
    If (TX = "") {
        Gui Color, White
        Gui -caption +toolwindow +AlwaysOnTop
        Gui font, s30 bold, Arial
        Gui add, text, vTX cRed TransColor, On
        Gui Show, % "x" A_ScreenWidth-300 " y" A_ScreenHeight-130, TRANS-WIN
        WinSet TransColor, White, TRANS-WIN
        TX := "On"
    } Else
        GuiControl % A_IsSuspended ? "Show" : "Hide", TX
}
```